# Как правильно вывести и обработать значения из json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть json файл: [ссылка](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&tag=latest)

Нужно вывести `"result":"659442832174589898951364"` - в формате `6594.42`, т.е. обрезать до 6 символов и поставить точку после 4-го символа.

Чтобы в итоге вышло: "Баланс: 6594.42 ETH"

Затем есть второй json: [ссылка](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice)

Отсюда нужно взять `"ethusd":"223.18"` и умножить на значение из предыдущего json (обрезанное 6594.42) и вывести в формате: "Баланс в USD: 1471742.65"

Сделал только вывод первого значения, над остальным голову ломаю, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

```
<script>
$(function(){
$.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0x311f71389e3DE68f7B2097Ad02c6aD7B2dDE4C71&tag=latest', function(data) {
            for(var i=0;i<data.result.length;i++){
                $('#ethdata').append(data.result[i]);
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: _обрезать до 6 символов и поставить точку после 4-го символа_ вы уверены, что данное число будет из 24 цифр и точку ставить после 4-го? Уверены, что строка это `баланс * 100 000 000 000 000 000 000`?

Comment: По указанной ссылке нет массива, поэтому ваш цикл просто выведет строку result

Comment: да, уверен. баланс в аккаунте именно такой!
да, цикл тут лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae&tag=latest', function(data) {
    var digits1 = data.result.substring(0, 4);
    var digits2 = data.result.substring(4, 6);
    var balance = digits1 + '.' + digits2;
    $.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice', function(data2) {
      var balanceUSD = balance * data2.result.ethusd;
      $('#result').text(balanceUSD.toFixed(2));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="result">Wait!</h1>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgMwxJ не срабатывает, в консоли пишет ошибку про переменную.

Comment: Исправил пример. Нажмите "выполнить код"

Comment: У вас ошибка была в условии `"ethusd":"223.18"` а по ссылке `result["ethusd":"223.18"]`